# Can a connected org be inherited by child bu in multi connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

While setting up a Marketing Cloud instance with multiple business units and multi org connect activated, I accidentally came across a way to have a child BU thats connected using the same API credentials as another BU (in the same instance) inherit all the synced objects.

Is this simply a bug? Or can this be used to connect multiple BU's to the same CRM instance without going above the 5 connected org limit (suggested by Salesforce).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but a known limitation.

Salesforce created a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381081&type=1) on it last year.

In short, if you want to have a different setup per BU, it is mandatory to utilize different SF org API users. Otherwise it will inherit the configuration.